# Computationally fastest way to make a new numpy array of every n elements from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose a 1-dimensional numpy array. I want to make a new array that contains every *n* elements. What is the **computationally fastest** way to do this?

Example:

```
a = numpy.arange(1,10)
b = numpy.fancytricks(a,?)
# b is now [2,4,6,8] if n = 2.
```

Edit: bolded important part of the question.

Comment: @jme That provides a way to accomplish the sampling goal, but makes no guarantees about speed.

Comment: What sort of guarantees about speed do you expect? Slicing in such a way returns a view of the data in `a` with a doubled stride length, so it takes constant time and incurs very little overhead.

Comment: @jme I am simply curious what the fastest protocol is, since I am working on a time-constrained problem that involves sampling large data.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found this sort of operation to be the bottleneck?

Comment: @jme No, but saving time at this stage would allow more time for more complex operations. I'm not expecting a miracle, just making sure I'm not missing out on any easy gains.

Comment: Time saved on the quick things is capped at the amount of time taken by the quick things. This probably won't save a second over the course of your whole program.

Comment: @jme you edited your comment well after writing it. And presumably downvoted a clear question. Can you prove your stride length claim? Afterall, the question you link to says it is not a constant time operation. Confusing.

Comment: @d0rmLife: No, slicing is constant time. Copying a slice isn't constant time, but you usually don't need to make a copy.

Comment: Nope, no downvote from me. The question linked to says "This creates a view of the the original data, so it's constant time." Below it talks about copying the slice, which is linear time. But if you don't copy, no linear time is needed. You can easily verify the claim with a simple `%%timeit`.

Comment: @jme Gotchya, thank you for clarifying. I guess the key to saving time in a case like this is to determine how essential the copy is. Thanks again.

Comment: @d0rmLife While many questions ask for **[fastest | lowest-latency]** a well prepared **quantitatively based experiment definition shall be a part of the StackOverflow MCVE convention**. Saying this, one may sketch a ***Cost Function:: 150.000$ x ManYearsInAlgoDevAlphaBetaTestTqmProdRelease + ( 60$ + 0.15$ x kWatts) x HoursDeltaSavedInProduction +...*** This will show real metrics' difference between smart solution and nonsensical proposals alike to develop language-X extension & finally get same,if not worse performance as other,read smarter,approaches. **Big-O's say why CostFunction $ave$**

Comment: Without context this question is close to meaningless.  What are you going to do with this new array?  For some purposes a `view` just delays the inevitable iteration and copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute fastest way to do this is to write an extension module in pure C and use the [buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) to access the data directly.  If you use [Cython](http://cython.org) or another such tool to write the C for you, you may see small amounts of performance lost in automatic reference counting.  Since you still have to do manual reference counting in handwritten C, the difference is likely to be negligible to nonexistent.

This will have marginally less overhead than the slicing syntax NumPy provides out of the box.  However, assuming you use NumPy correctly, the overall performance gain is likely to be small and constant, so it's not clear to me that this is worth the extra effort in any reasonable situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = a[1::step]
```

---

```
n = length(a)
```

**Computational cost** is `O(n)`, you are "making" a loop with `length(a)/step`

> UPDATE:
>   **Computational cost** is `O(1)`, there is no `numpy.array` object re-arrangement, just one constant <sub>... in access-method...</sub>  is set / changed. Once deployed, the access-speed is the same as with a value stored there before an update.

Comment: It is not Omega(n/step)?

Comment: Computational cost is `O(1)`. Basic slicing returns a view with altered stride length. There is no need to look through the array at all.

Comment: return a view with altered stride length has O(1) cost?

Comment: @juankirr Yes. Returning a view is just making a pointer, which is `O(1)`. Changing the stride length is also `O(1)`, since it's just updating a single number. You can time it to be sure... On my machine, `b = a[::2]` takes about 280 nanoseconds whether `a` has 100 entries or 100 million.